# how to solve run-time error 3704 in vb6.0?

Tags: vb6

just like yugal, I am getting error 3704-Operation not allowed when the object is closed.
Please help me fix this problem with my system..
this is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdLog_Click()
txtUser.SetFocus
frmChange.txtusern = txtUser
If txtUser <> "" And txtpass <> "" Then
    **Set rsenrol = cnenrol.Execute("Select * from tblUsers where username = '" & txtUser & "'and password='" & txtpass & "'")**[this is where the error occur]
    If csenrol.EOF = False Then
    MsgBox "Welcome " & txtUser & "!!", vbInformation, "Welcome User"
            txtUser = ""
            txtpass = ""
            Unload Me
            MDIfrm.Show
         Else
         MDIfrm.Visible = False
            MsgBox "Incorrect Username and/or Password. Please verify and Click Retry.", vbRetryCancel, "Log in Error"
            txtpass = ""
            txtUser.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If
Else
    MsgBox "Sorry, I cannot identify you.", vbExclamation, "Intruder Alert"
    MDIfrm.Visible = False
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks,
alex.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is very confusing. First, you mention VB6 in the question heading, and post VB code, but your tag says 'android'. Since VB6 and Android don't mix, it doesn't make sense. Second, you say "just like yugal", but there's no link to whatever you're referring to so we know what it is. Third, you don't post an actual question, but just a bunch of code and a reference to an error. Please edit it and include more information, and tag it with proper tags that relate to the question asked. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us on which line the error is raised? The Unload.Me looks suspicious to me.

Comment: So the error is on the line with the stars ** ?

Comment: I'd also worry about SQL injection using that sort of code.  You'd be much safer to use a parameter query instead... but that's just an off-topic suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Your Error is occuring because you are attempting to open a "SELECT" recordset with the execute command, this is used for action queries such as "INSERT, UPDATE" etc.  In this case you need to use the .open command with your ADO recordset.

Answer (score 0):

error >>     **Set rsenrol = cnenrol.Execute("Select * from tblUsers where username = '" & txtUser & "'and password='" & txtpass & "'")**[this is where the error occur]
<<

***new code***
dim sqls
If rsenrol.State = adStateOpen Then rsenrol.Close
sqls="Select * from tblUsers where username='" & txtUser & "'and password='" & txtpass & "'"
rsenrol.open sqls, cnenrol, 1, 2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).